# How do I integrate CKEditor into Yii2 without creating widget?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, ckeditor, assets

I looked at widgets [2amigos](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget) and [MihailDev](https://github.com/MihailDev/yii2-ckeditor). 
They both work fine like this:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
    'preset' => 'basic'
])
```

but I have to use only CKEditor assets without creating a widget.

```
CKEditorAsset::register($this);
$activeForm = ActiveForm::begin();
echo $activeForm->field($model, 'text')->textarea();
ActiveForm::end();
```

Of course this displays a simple textarea field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $activeForm->field($model, 'text')->textarea(['class'=>'ckeditor']);
```

This displays a text area with CKEditor options.
[ckeditor help](http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.4.0/samples/replacebyclass.html)